# Fill column in df.A based on comparison values in df.A and df.B

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

So I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

frame1 = {'Season': ['S19', 'S20', 'S21',
                     'S19', 'S20', 'S21',
                     'S19', 'S20', 'S21'],
          'DateFrom': ['2019-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2021-01-01',
                       '2019-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2021-01-01',
                       '2019-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2021-01-01'],
          'DateTo': ['2019-12-30', '2020-12-30', '2021-12-30',
                     '2019-12-30', '2020-12-30', '2021-12-30',
                     '2019-12-30', '2020-12-30', '2021-12-30'],
          'Currency': ['EUR', 'EUR', 'EUR',
                       'USD', 'USD', 'USD',
                       'MAD', 'MAD', 'MAD'],
          'Rate': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
          }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=frame1)

frame2 = {'Room': ['Double', 'Single', 'SeaView'],
          'Season': ['S20', 'S20', 'S19'],
          'DateFrom': ['2020-05-01', '2020-07-05', '2019-03-25'],
          'Currency': ['EUR', 'MAD', 'USD'],
          'Rate': [0, 0, 0]
          }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=frame2)
df1[['DateFrom', 'DateTo']] = df1[['DateFrom', 'DateTo']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df2[['DateFrom']] = df2[['DateFrom']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
print(df1.dtypes)
print(df2.dtypes)

df2['Rate'] = np.where((
                df2['Season'] == df1['Season'] &
                df2['Currency'] == df1['Currency'] &
                (df2['DateFrom'] > df1['DateFrom'] & df2['DateFrom'] < df1['DateTo'])
                        ), df1['Rates'], 'MissingData')

print(df2)
```

What I am trying to achieve is to fill Rate values in df2 with Rate values from df1 based on conditions where:

```
df2.Season == df1.Season &

df2.Currency == df1.Currency &

df2.DateFrom must be between df1.DateFrom and df1.DateTo
```

So my result in 'Rates' should be 2,8,4

I was hoping that code above will work but its not, i am getting error:

**"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'"**

Any help how to make it work will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can first merge then compare:

```
out = df1.merge(df2[['Season','Currency','DateFrom']],on=['Season','Currency'],
                                                            suffixes=('','_y'))
out = (out[out['DateFrom_y'].between(out['DateFrom'],out['DateTo'])]
      .reindex(columns=df1.columns).copy())
```

---

```
print(out)

  Season   DateFrom     DateTo Currency  Rate
0    S20 2020-01-01 2020-12-30      EUR     2
1    S19 2019-01-01 2019-12-30      USD     4
2    S20 2020-01-01 2020-12-30      MAD     8
```

EDIT per comments:

```
out = df1.merge(df2,on=['Season','Currency'],suffixes=('','_y'))
out = (out[out['DateFrom_y'].between(out['DateFrom'],out['DateTo'])]
       .reindex(columns=df2.columns).copy())

      Room Season    DateFrom Currency  Rate
0   Double    S20  2020-01-01      EUR     2
1  SeaView    S19  2019-01-01      USD     4
2   Single    S20  2020-01-01      MAD     8
```

Comment: Ok, that seems to work but what do I need to change if I want to have df2 as a result dataframe, not df1 ?